# How to export only some feature classes to xml using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, export, xml

I need to export some of the feature classes to an xml file ("export xml workspace") quite often so I'd like to automate the process. I've found an example [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000m8p000000) how to export a **feature dataset** to an xml file. I haven't been able to modify the code so that it would export only the feature classes I want (for example only the ones that start with a letter 'A'). I also need to export the tables and relationshipclasses (schema only).

Is this possible at all? I know there is an interface `IFeatureClassName`, but I don't know how to use it in this case.
Should this be done with arcpy instead?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 SP3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of getting the dataset:

```
// Retrieve the first feature dataset from the workspace.
IEnumDatasetName enumDatasetName = workspace.get_DatasetNames
    (esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureDataset);
```

You can get the feature class by:

```
IEnumDatasetName enumDatasetName = workspace.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass);
```

See this thread:

[Exporting/importing a geodatabase feature class to an XML file](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1707&t=233810)

**UPDATE**

You can get fc names within geodatabase/feature dataset using this code (solution in VB.NET):

```
Sub TestGetContents()

        Try
            Dim pGxApp As IGxApplication
            Dim Type As System.Type = System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(GetType(ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.AppRefClass).GUID)
            pGxApp = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type), ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.IGxApplication)
            'select geodatabase in Catalog tree
            If Not TypeOf pGxApp.SelectedObject Is IGxDatabase Then
                Debug.Print("select a geodb first")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim c As Collection
            c = GetContents(pGxApp.SelectedObject)
            Dim l As Long
            For l = 1 To c.Count
                Dim pName As IName
                pName = c.Item(l)
                If TypeOf pName Is IFeatureClassName Then
                    Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
                    pFC = pName.Open
                    MessageBox.Show(pFC.AliasName)

                ElseIf TypeOf pName Is IFeatureDatasetName Then
                    Dim pDSName As IDatasetName
                    pDSName = pName
                    MessageBox.Show(pDSName.Name)

                End If
            Next l
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub


    Function GetContents(ByVal pGxDB As IGxDatabase) As Collection

        Try
            Dim c As New Collection
            Dim pEnumDSName As IEnumDatasetName
            pEnumDSName = pGxDB.Workspace.DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny)
            Dim pDSName As IDatasetName
            pDSName = pEnumDSName.Next
            Do Until pDSName Is Nothing
                If TypeOf pDSName Is IFeatureClassName Then
                    c.Add(pDSName)
                ElseIf TypeOf pDSName Is IFeatureDatasetName Then
                    c.Add(pDSName)
                    AddSubNames(pDSName, c)
                End If
                pDSName = pEnumDSName.Next
            Loop
            GetContents = c
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Function

    Sub AddSubNames(ByVal pDSName1 As IDatasetName, ByVal c As Collection)
        Try
            Dim pEnumDSName As IEnumDatasetName
            pEnumDSName = pDSName1.SubsetNames
            pEnumDSName.Reset()
            Dim pDSName2 As IDatasetName
            pDSName2 = pEnumDSName.Next
            Do Until pDSName2 Is Nothing
                If TypeOf pDSName2 Is IFeatureClassName Then
                    c.Add(pDSName2)
                End If
                pDSName2 = pEnumDSName.Next
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Code referenced from this post:

[ArcObjects - enumerating feature classes and datasets within a geodatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509567/arcobjects-enumerating-feature-classes-and-datasets-within-a-geodatabase)

Comment: The example in the thread is pretty much the same I've already tried. I don't understand how do I filter the feature classes from the `IEnumDatasetName` object? The `(IName)name.NameString` always returns an empty string. I also get an exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040220) from `GenerateNameMapping` with the current code example...

Comment: @kor_, See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, so I have to cast the `IName` to `IFeatureClassName` or `IFeatureClass` and then open it, and THEN I have the actual name. How messy is that!

Answer (score 4):

If you are at 10.1, try using the [Export XML Workspace Document (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015s000000) geoprocessing tool.

I'm not sure exactly what it will do if you specify a feature class that participates in a relationship class, but I imagine it will include the relationship class and related object classes as well.