# Exporting only some feature classes to XML using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, xml, geodatabase-xml

Is it possible to only export **only some feature classes** when exporting a workspace to an XML document?

I know that when I am in ArcCatalog, I can right click my database --> Export XML Workspace Document. Then a GUI shows up and I can check-mark which features I want to include or exclude in my export.

What is the Arcpy equivalent of this manual export?

I found `arcpy.ExportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management(...)` function but the `in_data` parameter only seems to let me enter one feature class. It does not accept an array `["feature1", "feature2"]`.

I found this question using ArcObjects: [How to export only some feature classes to xml using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41590/how-to-export-only-some-feature-classes-to-xml-using-arcobjects?newreg=58773141bcda477ba75d4000b712b16b) 
But I am not familiar with ArcObjects and am hoping to write this script in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this as a two step process, i.e. export the layers to another geodatabase and then create the xml of the minimised content from that.
I know it is long winded, but it is a work around.

Comment: In the tool help https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015s000000 it says to do it this way, can you include this link and/or add a quote from the help document to support your answer then I can be comfortable upvoting it. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh I see, so this function will not do subsets. How is it that this is possible using the ArcCatalog GUI? Do you happen to know what function ArcCatalog is calling when I do the manual export?

Comment: No it wont do subsets, I've tried lists and tuples, relative paths and absolute paths and have concluded you can export only *one element* be it geodatabase, feature class or feature dataset. If you supply a geodatabase or feature dataset *all the feature classes contained will be exported*. Internally the XML export will be calling the function shown in your code sample IGdbXmlExport https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00260000005p000000, similar to http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/10fe68bf-01c4-4b50-8458-04cba2cd230a.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional resources!